# linux unzip excluding everything in the folder and underneath

Tags: linux, unzip

Hi I have to unzip a file that could have a Directory and I want to exclude everything within that directory, I tried lot of options and looked here as well, but doesn't seem to find any good solution.

These are the contents of the zip file: 
Please note the depth of EXCLUDE folder is unknown, but we have to exclude everything

```
    $unzip -l patch2.zip
Archive:  patch2.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2013-10-29 17:42   EXCLUDE/
        0  2013-10-29 17:24   EXCLUDE/inner/
        0  2013-10-29 17:24   EXCLUDE/inner/inner1.txt
        0  2013-10-29 15:45   EXCLUDE/file.txt
        0  2013-10-29 15:44   patch.jar
        0  2013-10-29 15:44   system.properties
---------                     -------
        0                     6 files
```

I tried this command, which only extract the files within it, but not the folder and its contents:

```
$unzip -l patch2.zip -x EXCLUDE/*
Archive:  patch2.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2013-10-29 17:42   EXCLUDE/
        0  2013-10-29 17:24   EXCLUDE/inner/
        0  2013-10-29 17:24   EXCLUDE/inner/inner1.txt
        0  2013-10-29 15:44   patch.jar
        0  2013-10-29 15:44   system.properties
---------                     -------
        0                     5 files
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to quote the exclude pattern so that it is passed to `unzip`. Otherwise it will be expanded by the shell before being passed to `unzip`.

Try:

```
unzip patch2.zip -x "EXCLUDE/*"
```

Comment: +1 for the answer as it's close to the OP's question. My own is just a "good to know" alternative ^^ (which is now little known, whereas it was quite more famous in the early linux days)

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. Can you please explain what do you mean by "it is passed to unzip. Otherwise it will be expanded by the shell before being passed to unzip".

Comment: @Ravi Read about [Globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) which is when the shell converts wildcard patterns into filenames. e.g, when you run `echo *`, the shell "expands" `*` into a list of filenames e.g. `file1`, `file2` etc before executing `echo`. As a result, `echo *` becomes `echo file1 file2`. The `echo` program never sees the wildcard, it only sees the arguments `file1` and `file2`. But, if you quote the pattern, `echo "*"`, the shell will not perform this expansion and the pattern will be passed as an argument to the program which can interpret it however it chooses.

Comment: To specify multiple exclusions, use this syntax: -x "pattern 1" "pattern 2" ..., do  not use -x "patern 1" -x "pattern 2", otherwise the 2nd -x will be treated as a matching pattern which will incur an caution message. I've googling but find this issue is rarely mentioned so I'd like to share this information for those who need it.

Answer (score 1):

@dogbane answer is right.

But I still add another [I hope] interresting option, as you are on linux:

```
mc
```

(aka: Midnight Commander)

Start it, and then : on the Right panel, navigate to where you want your files to end up, and on the Left panel, navigate "inside" the ZIP file, and at that first level select + copy the things you need (ie, select all, and unselect the EXCLUDE folder, for example)

`mc` is VERY flexible and nice to use, especially to tar/untar/zip/move/delete/rename files... (on windows, an equivalent is TotalCommander, and I use its "synchronise" option very often to keep backups and origin in sync). It allow you to navigate archives as if they were uncompressed (trying to minimize the actual decompression to just the "navigating" part so you don't uncompress them twice).